# Pandas df write to Excel template with prepared styles

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have DataFrame **df**.

I have Excel file **template_with_styles.xlsx** in which there is a color table ready.

I want to write **df** to a template.

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = load_workbook('template_with_styles.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=None, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
wb.save('my.xlsx')
```

As a result, I get: first comes my table with styles, and below is the data without styles.

How can I write DataFrame to a Ecxel using a prepared template?

Comment: I would recommend the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527992/pandas-dataframe-to-specific-sheet-in-a-excel-file-without-losing-formatting/73116312#73116312

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to do this. My attempt to convert to your example, from the following article with better explanations

https://pbpython.com/advanced-excel-workbooks.html

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('template_with_styles.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
wb = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
ws.add_table('A1:B10', {'style': 'Table Style Medium 20'})
writer.save()
```

Comment: In your example, styles are written in manual mode 'A1:B10', {'style': 'Table Style Medium 20'}. Is there a way to append dataframe to an already formatted Excel file?

Comment: No, I don't. Forgot to mention my answer was an alternative to your actual question.