# Start with templates XLSX file for pandas.to_excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

My question is similar/identical to this previous one, but checking for a more recent solution: [Pandas df write to Excel template with prepared styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314254/pandas-df-write-to-excel-template-with-prepared-styles)

I have set up a script to export several sheets of data to a spreadsheet, say the sheets are named "A" and "B", which is working fine.  I would like to create a template spreadsheet file where I have pre setup up all the sheets and specifically have a summary sheet, "Summary" which contains some simple equations pulling data from "A" and "B".  For my project requirements this must be done in the spreadsheet so the formulas are visible, and not in Python.  I may also want to do some formatting in that template which is simpler than in the script.

Is this possible?  The only thought I has was starting with read_excel, but this just brings in the data and loses formatting.